# R-How to handle subsetting in lists

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a list like this `y<-list(Ozone=100:112, Month=1:12, Temp=60:72)` I want to extract the elements i.e. of Ozone>108 and in a second query I want to extract (at the same time) the elements of Month and Temp for  Ozone>108.

So, (because it is an easy example) the output will be:

```
`$Ozone`
[1] 109 110 111 112

$Month

[1] 9 10 11 12

$Temp

[1] 69 70 71 72
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `sapply(y, function(x) x[which(y$Ozone > 108)])`

Comment: Notice that you have 13 elements in Ozone and Temp, but only 12 in Month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`y` is a list of vectors which is the definition of a data.frame and its offsprings data.table and tibble.

So you can convert `y` into a data.frame-like object and do the selection there:

```
y <- list(Ozone = 101:112, Month = 1:12, Temp = 61:72)
```

Note the different definition of list `y`: Each element is a vector of the same length 12.

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table 
DT <- as.data.table(y)

# select
DT[Ozone > 108, Ozone]
#[1] 109 110 111 112

DT[Ozone > 108]
#   Ozone Month Temp
#1:   109     9   69
#2:   110    10   70
#3:   111    11   71
#4:   112    12   72
```

Or in base R syntax:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(y)

DF[DF$Ozone > 108, "Ozone"]
#[1] 109 110 111 112

DF[DF$Ozone > 108, ]
#   Ozone Month Temp
#9    109     9   69
#10   110    10   70
#11   111    11   71
#12   112    12   72
```